# Pandas Dataframe separate multiple columns into bins and plot each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have the following `machines` dataframe, where it has two variables from different machines (first columns are power and the following are speed):

```
PCTimeStamp           VDB01   VDB02   VDB03  VDB01Speed VDB02Speed VDB03Speed

2021-02-21 00:00:00   2174.6  2022.5  2112.8  11.0  10.0    10.5
2021-02-21 00:10:00   2198.8  2096.4  2153.9  11.5  10.5    11.0
2021-02-21 00:20:00   2198.6  2133.2  2184.4  11.5  11.0    11.0
```

I would like to separate each machine' speed into bins (in 0.5 steps) and get the median power for every bin for every machine and then plot it for each column (each machine). I was able to separate the bins but I can't find a way to get the median for each bin for each column.

This is what I have so far:

```
# Bin the dataframe with 41 bins with 0.5 steps:
bins = np.linspace(reference['wind'].min(), reference['wind'].max(), len(refCurve))

# Group by bins
groups = teste['VDB1-01_Ambient WindSpeed'].groupby(np.digitize(machines['VDB1-01'], bins))

# Takes median:
groups.median()

def graph_WT():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    
    plt.plot(machines['VDB01Speed'],machines["VDB1-01"])
    plt.xlabel("Wind speed (m/s)", fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel("Power (kW)", fontsize=16)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
        
graph_WT()
```

I was trying to do individually for each column, but even if I got that right, it wouldn't be what I'm looking for. The plot is also working fine, but I must addapt it to plot each column.

Any help is really appreciated!

**** EDIT ****

I almost got what I'm looking for with `pd.cut`, but I don't want values to be in ranges such as (3.5, 4], (4, 4.5], etc. This is what I have now:

```
# If ratio is between 0 and 20, we get the bins spaced by .05
def get_bins(s):
    return pd.cut(s,np.arange(0,20,0.5))
    
# vdbW = dataframe with only WIND values
# vdbP = dataframe with only POWER values
# custom_round = function to round wind values by 0.5

# Get bin assignments for each machine
bins = vdbW.applymap(lambda x: custom_round(x, base=0.5)).apply(get_bins,axis=1)
bins.columns = vdbP.columns
# Get the mean of each group for each machine
df = vdbP.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(bins[x.name]).agg("median"))
df
```

which gives me the following output:

```
            VDB1-01 VDB1-02 VDB1-03 
(3.5, 4.0]  95.95   103.10  81.50
(4.0, 4.5]  170.40  176.50  168.60
(4.5, 5.0]  270.15  252.90  256.40
```

Any ideas on how I could to the same exact thing to individual bin values (median for 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, ...) instead of ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might come across this same problem as me, I got a solution and I'll post it down here.

First I rounded my wind values by 0.5 so when I cut in bins, I would end up having ranges as (2.5, 3.0], meaning that this "range" would only actually refer to 3.0m/s, because my values were already rounded by 0.5, i.e., the first value of the range wouldn't be in the range, since its open "(".

Here is the code:

```
def custom_round(x, base=0.5):
    return float(base * round(float(x)/base))

# If ratio is between 0 and 20, we get the bins spaced by .05
def get_bins(s):
    return pd.cut(s,np.arange(0,20,0.5))
    
    
# Get bin assignments for each machine
bins = vdbW.dropna().applymap(lambda x: custom_round(x, base=0.5)).apply(get_bins,axis=1)
bins.columns = vdbP.columns
# Get the mean of each group for each machine
df = vdbP.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(bins[x.name]).agg("median"))
df.index = df.index.right

# Plot the data
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(df.index,df["VDB1-01"])
plt.show()
```